# SOLVED - Completely frozen on bootscreen (unresponsive)

Tags: dual-boot, freeze, 23.10

I think I have a code red with this one - it's frozen at the worst possible point where the boot options menu has been disabled, and before it has registered the power button.

https://i.imgur.com/8qmbqV4.jpeg

I've tried holding down the power button, but as aforementioned, it does nothing. It has seemingly frozen at a point where it cannot be interrupted. I can hear the fans whirring, and I think my only hope is to wait for it to run out of battery.

Yes, I dualboot Windows because I need to use some Windows-specific software. If anyone has some black magic hotkeys, please share them. I am using Ubuntu 23.10.

EDIT: Ok it's getting a little toasty... Will there be some lower-level safety feature that shuts it off it if gets too hot? I'm nervous that I'll have to open it up and disconnect the power source or something.

EDIT2: it's ok, it ran out of power just now and it seems to be working alright.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, it's ok :) it ran out of power and, at least, Windows is working fine.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1345011)

Comment: @zx485 I think you misunderstand. I was asking for a way to shutdown Ubuntu in a place where it is seemingly impossible, but the reason I had for doing that resolved itself on it's own. The "answer" was just waiting for the power to run down and let the system reboot by itself, which I marked as the answer to this thread.

Comment: Well then... running out of power is a rare way of solving a problem. The question remains if it's reproducible... However, if it solved your problem, nevermind.